# Code 0xc0000005 CasperJs Phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs, slimerjs

We got this error on the command prompt

```
"# waitForExec() tests
Fatal Windows exception, code 0xc0000005.
PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the bug reporting guide at
<http://phantomjs.org/bug-reporting.html> and file a bug report."
```

Can someone help we with that?

I installed phantomjs, slimerjs and casperjs with node (node install -g).
phantomjs version: 2.1.1
slimerjs version: does not even start properly, complaining about the FireFox version not being compatible
casper version: 1.1.4